# Change color of code and comments to RStudio standard syntax colors

Tags: r, knitr

I'm using knitr on Mac OSX to output a PDF (LaTeX) and want to change the color of syntax in the output to standard coloring in RStudio. This means comments should be green, numeric values blue, characters green, all other syntax black.

I've messed around with Sweavel.sty but can't get it to work.

Can somebody give me exact instructions on how I can change colors?
Should I create a new sty file?
Where should I put it for this given project only?
What else do I need to do to make my Rnw file call that sty file?
Anything else?

Thanks!

EDIT: I made my question more concrete and provide a code example:

This is the code I have in my Rnw file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}  
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\begin{document}

<<>>=
#Here comes a comment
a <- 1

#Here another comment
(a <- 2)
@

\end{document}
```

When I compile this I get this in a PDF:
[image: ![enter image description here]

I need the comments and the character string 'test' to be green, the numbers and keyword library to be blue, and everything else black. That would be standard in RStudio. Example:

[image]

How do I modify the code above to make that happen? The only thing that I want to be different is the grey background.

Comment: How do you compile your file? p.s. next time try to put your question in a more precise way when you ask not after users have already tried to help you. That will save your and others time

Comment: Yes I'm sorry @SabDem, I will make sure to do that in the future. I'm working in the RStudio gui and just hitting 'Compile PDF' (shift command K).

Answer (score 1):

An answer/comment because of dimension:

There are several ways to do that. One way is to keep the `.tex` file by using the option `keep_tex = TRUE` in the yaml front matter and then edit the LaTeX file... of course you have to be very proficient in that language (example next).

Another very short way is with the `highlight: <option>` where option can be chosen among one of the options available [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#syntax-highlighting) and see if one of those is right for your purposes.

Another one, without using knitr but sweave, is to compile the LaTeX file but like the firs case you must have some proficiency in LaTeX programming.

#### An example with keep_tex: TRUE

If you inspect the `.tex` file that option allows you to keep, you will see a lot of `\newcommand`. Most of them are used to create the syntax highlighting. You have to modify those definitions. For example:

```
\newcommand{\CommentTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textit{{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\CommentVarTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
```

define the comment in a [green](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~pknowles/colour.html):

```
\newcommand{\CommentTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.39, 0.98, 0.28}{\textit{{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\CommentVarTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.39, 0.98, 0.28}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
```

You will have green comments:

[image]